# finding list of elements in the local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm storing json strings representing objects in the local storage. I write something like this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('ItemID' + TheItemID, TheItemInJson);
```

Now I need to know which items are in the storage. What's a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841029/listing-localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to use this code:

```
for(var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    console.log(key + " => " + value);
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks; it looks like this is the only way. I wanted to avoid this because my local store is quite large so it needs to read a lot from disk to get the info. Thanks anyway.